# I encounter a server error when I try to use a session storing user information from post in php

Tags: php

```
    // first page
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email2'];

    // second page
    session_start();
    echo "Welcome Admin User: ".$_SESSION['email'];
```

My code isn't working it encounters a server error when I try to login. It was working before I added the sessions. Can anyone help?

Comment: general tip: if you get an error message, TELL US WHAT THE ERROR MESSAGE IS. there is NOTHING in your code sample that would even remotely let us figure out what's really wrong. At best we could guess, and we've got better things to do than play 20 questions

Comment: something tells me its a headers already sent error, since the OP said everything was fine before they added the SESSION code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a multitude of things but do this for a start, look at your php settings i.e print out phpinfo and look at session.save_path, make sure the directory exists as in phpinfo.